# " unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1f5ea840" when passing values from one ViewController to next in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I'm getting this error when passing values from one viewcontroller to the next:

```
"unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1f5ea840"
"'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController setContainerToLocationFromResultVC:]: "
```

I've created a strong property in the 2nd VC and it seemed to work well until I made some modifications to use Container View.

Here's my code:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"resToContainerSegue"]) {
containerViewController *containerVC= segue.destinationViewController;

containerVC.container_toLocationFromResultVC=self.toLabel.text; // also tried "toLabel.text" but no use.

containerVC.container_fromLocationFromResultVC=self.fromLabel.text;
}
}
```

Please let me know if I need to provide any more specific. 
I'd be very glad for any help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [unrecognized selector sent to instance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455161/unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance)

Comment: @H2CO3 Haha :D I just laughed :D

Answer (score 3):

I got the answer: My destination viewController was not pointing to the proper class. Thanks everyone for helping :)