# [__NSCFString _isResizable]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa7a52e0

Tags: ios, uitableview, sqlite, uiimageview

I have image URL strings in database. Then I retrieving the images and add to productimg_array. I need to show the productimg_array images to `UITableView cell`. I'm using imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[productimg_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
 But app crashing.

```
const char *sql = "SELECT id,cat_id,product_image,order_by,description FROM product";

        NSLog(@"sql is %s",sql);

        sqlite3_stmt *statement;

        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
            // We "step" through the results - once for each row.



            while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {


                product_image = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
                                 (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)];
              //  NSLog(@"product_image is %@",product_image);

                [productimg_array addObject:product_image];


         }
        }
```

TableView:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    NSLog(@"productimg_array is %lu",(unsigned long)[productimg_array count]);

    return [productimg_array count];


}




- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }


for(int i=0; i<[productimg_array count];i++){

[cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[productimg_array objectAtIndex:i]]
               placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];


}

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    return cell;

}
```

Comment: How is `product_image` declared?

Comment: where it is crashing?

Comment: After removing this line cell.imageView.image = [productimg_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; It's wokring. But image is not showing

Comment: @user3073276 see mu updated answer. If productimg_array have Url string then it will show your image. Better go with Lazy Laoding in such scenerion.

Comment: ok. I think i need to use SDWebImage.

Comment: Yes you can use that. https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Comment: possible duplicate of [unrecognized selector sent to instance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455161/unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cell.imageView.image = [productimg_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

here `cell.imageView.image`  expect an image in the position but the array has a set of strings that you are passing to set in the imageview

```
 cell.imageView.image =[UIImage imageNamed:[productimg_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

**Note :**

```
product_image = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)];
```

can crash if the `product_image` is empty or null in db,so do this

```
char *nameChars = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2);
if (nameChars) {
   product_image = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:nameChars];
}
```

Comment: I changed my code with SDWebImage. But one image showing all the cell.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to download that images from URL location and then you have to assign it to your image view.For this you can use lazy loading.