# [__NSCFString size]: Exception - Objective-C (Xcode)

Tags: ios, exception, core-data, crash

I have an app based around a core data model and I am loading a data point back into a view controller. Here is the excpetion that I am getting:

```
 -[__NSCFString size]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc530dd0
```

With exception breakpoints on, I have found that this line is causing the exception:

```
[self.MyImage setImage:[self.device valueForKey:@"imagename"]];
```

This is quite a weird error, as this line works:

```
[self.StepItTitle setText:[self.device valueForKey:@"title"]];
```

Why is it crashing? What do I need to fix to prevent this from happening?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: The exception says that you are calling `size` on a string object, which of course does not have that method. What is the result of `[self.device valueForKey:@"imagename"]` ? Try with `NSLog(@"%@", [self.device valueForKey:@"imagename"]);`

Comment: @Neeku My question has been clarified above.

Comment: And I forgot: I imagine `MyImage` is an `NSImage` object? You should add some more information: at least type of objects, what is inside the `self.device` object.

Comment: @Francesco When using NSLog before the crash, it shows the correct image name, exactly how I want.

Comment: @C-O-D-E the reason why I asked for `NSLog` output is that usually it prints the class name. For what you told me I expect that the object referenced by the key @"imagename" is a string then?

Comment: When it crashes what do you see when you type this in the debugger? `po 0xc530dd0` or whatever the instance happens to be?

Comment: @Francesco Yep. The object is a string. I want my image to change to an image with the string from the core data model.

Comment: +1 for editing and clarifying. Always try to search well before asking, and once you asked, provide as much detail, including code and screenshots, as possible. (:
Although: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @C-O-D-E And what is `self.MyImage`? an `UIImageView` ? Then you should do something `[self.MyImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[self.device valueForKey:@"imagename"]]];`

Comment: @Francesco It worked! Thanks a ton! Post an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: @C-O-D-E detailed answer added

Comment: possible duplicate of [unrecognized selector sent to instance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455161/unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance)

Comment: I suggest you read https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/CodingGuidelines.html and follow it so that it's easier for others to read and understand your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Giving the comments to your question I add the following things:

`self.MyImage` is a reference to an object of type `UIImageView` and `[self.device valueForKey:@"imagename"]` returns an `NSString` with the image name.

Having said that, the exception clearly states that you (or the framework) is calling `size` to an `NSString` object. `NSString` does not have the method, thus the reason for the exception.

What you want to do instead, is to create a `UIImage` given a filename and set it to the view.
To achieve this you have to do the following

```
NSString *filename = [self.device valueForKey:@"imagename"];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:filename]; //This loads an image if present in the main bundle
[self.MyImage setImage:image];
```

Of course you can do the same in just one line of code, but I expended for clarity.