# Date picker controller in iOS

Tags: ios

I want to use date picker in my app . but when i select date from date picker than this code showing exception .Exception is

> [AppointmentViewController PickerAction:]: unrecognized selector sent 
>   to instance 0x7fbbfa5f9d60'

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];

NSString *formatedDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:self.DatePicker.date];

self.SelectedDate.text =formatedDate;
self. DatePicker.hidden=NO;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [unrecognized selector sent to instance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455161/unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance)

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement selector method for date picker like below:

UIDatePicker *myPicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];

```
myPicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
myPicker.minimumDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:0];
myPicker.maximumDate = [NSDate date];
[myPicker addTarget:self action:@selector(datePickerValueChanged:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
 NSDate *mydate = myPicker.date;
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
[self.txtDOB setInputView:myPicker];
```

- (void)datePickerValueChanged:(id)sender{
  UIDatePicker *picker = (UIDatePicker *)sender;
  NSString *dateString;

  NSDate *mydate = picker.date;
  NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
  [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
  dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:mydate];
  [self.txtDOB setText:dateString];
  }