# [__NSCFString objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, unrecognized-selector

I am using a `UITtableView` and when I click on specific `UIButton` in a specific `UITableViewCell` i want to get some data. So here is my code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
cell1.btndelete.tag = indexPath.row
        cell1.btndelete.addTarget(self, action: "buttonClicked:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

an in this function i am getting perticualr insex

```
func buttonClicked(sender:UIButton) {
    let dic = downloadeddata.objectAtIndex(0) as! NSDictionary
    print(dic)


    let buttonRow = sender.tag
    print(buttonRow)
    let index:Int? = Int(buttonRow)

    let filepath = dic["path"]?.objectAtIndex(index!)
    print(filepath)
}
```

But while I get the data in `filepath` its throw an error

> [__NSCFString objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance so what is the issue?

This is my array(downloadeddata) data:

```
(    
        {
        content = "";
        file = "http://radio.spainmedia.es/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/tailtoddle_lo4.mp3";
        image = "http://radio.spainmedia.es/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/forbes.jpg";
        number = 0001;
        path = "/Users/itechnotion-mac1/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4785CE7B-7642-45BF-A2E1-7C8FCF7986F9/data/Containers/Data/Application/500EC1B3-E2A4-469E-BF41-9FBE30313BBA/Documents/podcasts/forbes/tailtoddle_lo4.mp3";
        subtitle = "Titular forbes";
        title = "Forbes 1";
    },
        {
        content = "En este primer programa se tratar\U00e1n asuntos tan importante como este y aquel sin descuidar un poco de todo lo dem\U00e1s";
        file = "http://radio.spainmedia.es/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/ogilvy.mp3";
        image = "http://radio.spainmedia.es/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/tapas.jpg";
        number = 0001;
        path = "/Users/itechnotion-mac1/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4785CE7B-7642-45BF-A2E1-7C8FCF7986F9/data/Containers/Data/Application/500EC1B3-E2A4-469E-BF41-9FBE30313BBA/Documents/podcasts/tapas/ogilvy.mp3";
        subtitle = Titulareando;
        title = "Tapa 1";
    }
)
```

Every time I try, I am getting the same result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unrecognized selector sent to instance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455161/unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance)

Answer (score 1):

`dic["path"]?` returns you a string not array.

Comment: edited my qoestion and posted array data.. @anoopvaidya

Comment: i know this but everytime i get this string "tailtoddle_lo4.mp3" even when i clicked on ogilvy.mp3 i am getting this string "tailtoddle_lo4.mp3"

Answer (score 1):

This line `dic["path"]?.objectAtIndex(index!)`throwing the error because  `dic["path"]`returns string not an array. If you want array, then use `[dic allKeys]/[dic allValues]`.

Access the `button.tag` then pass that `tag` value as `index` then you will get the required `string`. 
To access the path value use `[dic objectForKey:@"path"];`

```
func buttonClicked(sender:UIButton) {
    let dic = downloadeddata.objectAtIndex(sender.tag) as! NSDictionary
    print(dic)

    let filepath = dic["path"]
    print(filepath)
}
```

Comment: but i want to string

Answer (score 0):

you already used indxPath.row to retrive dic object from that array so dic only contains

```
 {
        content = "";
        file = "http://radio.spainmedia.es/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/tailtoddle_lo4.mp3";
        image = "http://radio.spainmedia.es/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/forbes.jpg";
        number = 0001;
        path = "/Users/itechnotion-mac1/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4785CE7B-7642-45BF-A2E1-7C8FCF7986F9/data/Containers/Data/Application/500EC1B3-E2A4-469E-BF41-9FBE30313BBA/Documents/podcasts/forbes/tailtoddle_lo4.mp3";
        subtitle = "Titular forbes";
        title = "Forbes 1";
    }
```

now you only need fetch that path string for dic

so   `dic["path"]` will return you a string. so just write   `let filepath = dic["path"] as! String`
according that your final output is like

```
func buttonClicked(sender:UIButton) {
    let dic = downloadeddata.objectAtIndex(0) as! NSDictionary
    print(dic)


    let buttonRow = sender.tag
    print(buttonRow)
    let index:Int? = Int(buttonRow)

    let filepath = dic["path"] as! String
    print(filepath)
}
```