# unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f90f1f04180

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, unrecognized-selector

I'm a newbie to swift. I'm using xcode version 8 beta 4. I'm having an error whenever I scroll through my Date Picker. I have read a [very similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455161/unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance), but the answer there is not fixing my problem. Below is my code:

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
    textField.inputView = datePicker
    datePicker.addTarget(self, action: Selector("datePickerChanged:"), for: .valueChanged)        
}

func datePickerChanged(sender: UIDatePicker){
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .long
    dateLog.text = formatter.string(from: sender.date)
}
```

when I click on my textfield the `UIDatePicker` is showing up just fine, but when I start to scroll through the dates, it gives me the following error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MyApp.ViewController datePickerChanged:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f90f1f04180'

Comment: your selector should be written like this `#selector(datePickerChanged(_:))`

Comment: and the method `func datePickerChanged(_ sender: UIDatePicker) {`

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanks! it worked! I changed it to:    `datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(datePickerChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Selector(String)` is deprecated. You should start using the new syntax `#selector`.

Also, the colon at the end is not needed.

So, your code should look like this:

```
datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(datePickerChanged), 
    for: .valueChanged)
```

Comment: @vadian I know. I tried OPs's code and it didn't crash. But nonetheless, the non-deprecated syntax should always be used imo.

Comment: Thanks! It worked! I also did it this way and it also worked: `datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(datePickerChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)` but i had to change my datePickerChanged function too: `func datePickerChanged(_ sender: UIDatePicker)`

Answer (score -1):

1. change the `Selector` to `#selector`
2. change `for` to `forControlEvents`
3. change `.valueChanged` to `.ValueChanged`

   ```
   datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(yourClass.datePickerChanged), forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
   ```

Comment: He is probably using Swift 3