# I got a strange error when using (tk backend of) matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I got a strange error when using (tk backend of) matplotlib. I know the apis are changed in the lastest stable version, so I have to change the codes. No problem when using old version. How do I fix it?

```
2018-11-20 20:29:57.126 Python[60013:847240] -[NSApplication _setup:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f8695fc4a30
2018-11-20 20:29:57.129 Python[60013:847240] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSApplication _setup:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f8695fc4a30'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff3eb09fcb __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff657c3c76 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff3eba2a24 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff3ea80610 ___forwarding___ + 1456
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff3ea7ffd8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   libtk8.6.dylib                      0x000000011ec631f2 TkpInit + 408
    6   libtk8.6.dylib                      0x000000011ebd2aac Initialize + 2454
    7   _tkinter.cpython-36m-darwin.so      0x000000011b1f3dd4 Tcl_AppInit + 84
    8   _tkinter.cpython-36m-darwin.so      0x000000011b1f3aab _tkinter_create + 1115
    9   Python                              0x000000010d2e0e1b _PyCFunction_FastCallDict + 491
    10  Python                              0x000000010d363a87 call_function + 439
    11  Python                              0x000000010d3601f7 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 27559
    12  Python                              0x000000010d3644ef _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 2447
    13  Python                              0x000000010d3650bb _PyFunction_FastCallDict + 763
    14  Python                              0x000000010d297e57 _PyObject_FastCallDict + 247
    15  Python                              0x000000010d297f75 _PyObject_Call_Prepend + 149
    16  Python                              0x000000010d297c90 PyObject_Call + 96
    17  Python                              0x000000010d2f904d slot_tp_init + 125
    18  Python                              0x000000010d2f5279 type_call + 313
    19  Python                              0x000000010d297e25 _PyObject_FastCallDict + 197
    20  Python                              0x000000010d363988 call_function + 184
    21  Python                              0x000000010d3601f7 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 27559
    22  Python                              0x000000010d3644ef _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 2447
    23  Python                              0x000000010d364da1 fast_function + 545
    24  Python                              0x000000010d363a61 call_function + 401
    25  Python                              0x000000010d360296 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 27718
    26  Python                              0x000000010d3644ef _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 2447
    27  Python                              0x000000010d359584 PyEval_EvalCode + 100
    28  Python                              0x000000010d38f5f1 PyRun_FileExFlags + 209
    29  Python                              0x000000010d38ee62 PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags + 882
    30  Python                              0x000000010d3a8db2 Py_Main + 3554
    31  Python                              0x000000010d283df8 Python + 3576
    32  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff663b3115 start + 1
    33  ???                                 0x0000000000000003 0x0 + 3
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["unrecognized selector sent to instance" error in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455161/unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-error-in-objective-c)

Comment: Without a [mcve], not much else we can do.

Comment: Are you creating multiple plots at the same time and/or in threads?