# I got Crash when integrating Applovin Max Ad iOS

Tags: ios, swift, ads, applovin

I am trying to integrate Applovin Ad into my project. But I get a crash when trying to integrate

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM al_isValidString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x28116aa30'`

Below is my code:

`ALSdk.shared()!.mediationProvider = ALMediationProviderMAX ALSdk.shared()!.initializeSdk(completionHandler: { _ in })`

I tried creating new project and it works. But on my project still Crash. My project integrates admob, iron ads and applovin

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["unrecognized selector sent to instance" error in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455161/unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-error-in-objective-c)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the error at this line

```
ALSdk.shared()!.mediationProvider = ALMediationProviderMAX
```

I use Cocoapods to install

```
pod 'AppLovinSDK'
```

It creates 2 paths to that file. But when I click on it, it still only points to 1 file

[See this photo to know more](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3aTG.png)

That makes xcode not know which file's func to use. And generate the above error. Hope this helps everyone