# Check if Protocol Method is Defined

Tags: ios, objective-c-runtime, uiscrollviewdelegate

[`UIScrollViewDelegate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html) has a new awesome method:

```
// called on finger up if the user dragged. velocity is in points/second. targetContentOffset may be changed to adjust where the scroll view comes to rest. not called when pagingEnabled is YES
- (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView 
                     withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity 
              targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA,__IPHONE_5_0)
```

However, this is **ONLY available in iOS 5**.  For iOS's without this method, I'd like to use paging as an alternative.  So I'm left with two options:

1. Check the iOS version, *which I don't know how to do*, or
2. Check to see if this method is defined for the [`UIScrollViewDelegate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html) protocol, *which I also don't know how to do*.

I would prefer to somehow check if the method is defined in the protocol rather than checking the iOS version.  Note that doing a `respondsToSelector:` check won't be adequate since my class implementing the protocol will always define it.

Comment: +1 for interesting question on availability of protocol members.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
BOOL isAtLeastIOS5 = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 5.0;
```

See [How to test a protocol for a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271454/how-to-test-a-protocol-for-a-method/4271987#4271987) to test the protocol for a given method.

Comment: Nitpicking... rename BOOL to isAtLeastIOS5 ;)

Comment: +1 That looks easy enough and may be what I use.  I'd still like to figure out how to check if the protocol defines the method.  I wonder if something similar to `instancesRespondsToSelector:` would work.  Still trying to figure it out myself...  I'll accept this as answer if I don't see anything better.

Comment: `[[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] > 4.3;` is true for iOS 4.3.3, so this should be `[[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 5.0;`