# why doesn't my action respond to the selector?

Tags: ios, uilabel, subclass

I've subclassed a UILabel and added 2 properties that look like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) SEL action;
@property (nonatomic, assign) id target;
```

I then implemented UIView's touches began method like this:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    if ([target respondsToSelector:@selector(action)]) {
        [target performSelector:@selector(action) onThread:[NSThread mainThread] withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
    }
}
```

within the class containing the subclassed UILabel, i set the target and action like this:

```
    label.target = self;
    labek.action = @selector(myMethod);
    label.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

The class including the label does indeed have the method myMethod, and so it should respond to it. Any ideas why it might not?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting your action like this `label.action = @selector(myMethod);` and then using action and passing it into a second selector `[target respondsToSelector:@selector(action)]`.  That will not work.

You want to do this:

```
if ([target respondsToSelector:self.action]) {
    [target performSelector:self.action onThread:[NSThread mainThread] withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
}
```

Basically, the if statement fails because the target does not respond to that selector. Therefore, it is never being called.

Answer (score 0):

Do you get any errors in debug console?

How about

```
@selector(myMethod:) // with colon.
```

[Selectors in Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/738622/selectors-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that the label is contained in the bounds of the superview